# ConnectionString problem.Can not communicate with database after iis deployment

Tags: c#, sql-server, postman

After publishing my locat asp.net website to IIS server, it can not communicate with database. I'm checking if the api are working properly with Postman. And here is the error.

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="HsptlMgmnt" connectionString="server=amso1; database=hoptialfinaldb;Trusted_Connection=false;uid=tanvir;password=1234;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

  </connectionStrings>
```

[image: POSTMAN SCREENSHOT]

Comment: Your username/password is wrong.

Comment: @SyntaxError or, to be fair, the username/password is correct but the *server* is wrong :)

Comment: I've changed the password & checked it again and again.... Username password is correct...